# Save button's new state when exiting the app

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to have a button in my app which gets hidden after the first time it's tapped.
So what should I do to save it's hidden property after terminating the app?
And the second thing to ask is almost the same:
How can I change the frame of it after terminating the app?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would probably recommend saving a value in `NSUserDefaults` Maybe a BOOL for Hidden and check it on start up.  An example with a bool would be:

set:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: YES forKey @"someKey"];
```

get:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```

could do the same for any object using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: id forKey @"someKey"];
```

Comment: After setting the value, you should also call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] syncronize];` to make sure it gets saved.

Comment: save state every time it change. not on app termination. some times you will not have the chance.

Comment: Thank you;
What about the button's frame ?

Comment: @picciano There is no need to call `synchronize`. Values are saved automatically.